# Wordpress (database); Show last modified date?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

How can I show the last modified date, when my Mysql-database was updated?

(I know there is plugin for showing latest modified date for post/pages, I want to do similar, but show when fields/metadata was updated)

Thankful for answers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database_name LIKE 'table_name';");
foreach ($result as $data) {
    $updatetime = $data->Update_time;
}

$date = substr($updatetime, 0, -3);
echo $date;

?>
```

Comment: This is amazing! how to show only the date without the time?